# "I thought that he was wrong" or "I thought he was wrong"

Tags: grammar

**"I thought that he was probably wrong"** or **"I thought he was probably wrong"**
which one is correct?

Comment: What effort have you yourself made to find out the answer? For example, have you looked at the huge amount of resources on the Internet?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I couldn't find my answer.

Comment: Here's a link that you may find helpful [link](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv336.shtml)

Comment: Here is Iran and many sites including BBC are filtered. I am trying to break the filter. It is not very easy sometimes. I should do that to read your link. any way thank you for your reply.

Comment: I read the link but I could not find my answer there.

Comment: It's all there. It even mentions the verb "thought".

Comment: well, I read that link again. I guess it says that both sentences are correct. Am I right?

Comment: You are right; the "that" in your sentence is completely optional, and the meaning doesn't change if it's included or omitted. It's what we call a matter of _style_, not _grammar_. In future questions, you might want to try to tell us what you looked for when you researched the problem yourself. Telling us nothing tells us nothing. Telling us, "I looked but I couldn't find anything" tells us you at least made an effort, but we still have no clue what you even looked for, much less what you found. I suggest something more like, "I searched for ABC, I found XYZ, but I'm still not sure."

Comment: @ARAM Yes, in many instances the subordinator "that" is optional. The BBC Learning English website explains it all much better than anyone here could.

Comment: Well, I searched "I thought that he" and "I thought he". I found some examples of the second but I didn't find examples of the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From additional comments currently below your question, you are right that *I thought he* [seems more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20thought%20that%20he%2C%20I%20thought%20he&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20thought%20that%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20thought%20he%3B%2Cc0) than *I thought that he*.

[image: Thought "that" NGram.]

This is from Google Books NGram Viewer. It shows the frequency of words in books that it tracks. (But note that it doesn't track verbal or conversational use of words.)

So, in terms of usage, you could say that the former is more idiomatic. (Again, if just considering printed material.) It also explains why your searches would turn up more instances of one versus the other.

But there are many words and constructions that are seldom used that are still grammatical—even if they aren't as common.

In terms of actual grammar in this case, both sentences are fine.

Many people think it sounds more natural to drop *that* as much as possible. In other words, they think it's a filler word that is used too often. That may or may not be true (it's a matter of style and opinion), but the use of *that* is still grammatical—even if its not always used.